# Why does base aspirin hydrolysis work better than acid aspirin hydrolysis?

Tags: acid-base, catalysis, hydrolysis

Why does base aspirin hydrolysis work better than acid aspirin hydrolysis?
I conducted an experiment and found that there was greater Salicylic Acid yield for the one I added base compared to the one I added acid. Why is this so?

Comment: In what solvent system was this run?

Comment: I believe ethanol and water

Comment: Possibly aspirin is less soluble in acidic EtOH/water than in basic EtOH/water.

Comment: Does [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/147092/61578) answer your question?

Comment: Also, the mechanism given in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00995a007) explains why base is better catalysis.

Comment: Rush to close.  Unfortunately, no one checked the pKa of salicylic acid:  right around 3.  This indicates the 6 membered intramolecular carboxylate intermediate is indeed a viable weak acid hydrolysis mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Base (OH-) is the perfect nucleophile for ester hydrolysis of acetylsalicylic acid.

Acid pronation of the ester carboxyl group, which is further conjugated with benzene ring, and the far weaker OH2 nucleophile, will not work as well.

Base (and heat) hydrolysis is preferred, leaving carboxylate and OH groups.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Le Chatlier's rule. Since the hydrolysis produces acid, base catalysts will remove the products (the acid), shifting the reaction.